# How to convert following into a Binary Tree?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

What is the procedure to convert following into a binary tree? And what will be the output/answer ?                       A+(B+C+D+E)+F/G

Answer (score 0):

**A**+(B+C+D+E)+F/G

```
result
|
A
```

A+**(B+C+D+E)**+F/G

```
result
|   \
A   obj1
```

A+(B+C+D+E)+**F/G**

```
result
|   \
A   obj2
   /   \
 obj1   F/G(could be linked to A for load balancing)
```

(**B**+C+D+E)

```
result
|   \
A   obj2
   /   \
 obj1   F/G
 /
B
```

(B+**C**+D+E)

```
result
|   \
A   obj2
   /   \
 obj1   F/G
 / \
B   C
```

(B+C+**D**+E)

```
result
|   \
A   obj2
   /    \
 obj3    F/G
  |  \
 obj1  D
 / \
B   C
```

(B+C+D+**E**)

```
result
|   \
A   obj2
   /    \
 obj4    F/G
  |   \
 obj3  E
  |  \
 obj1  D
 / \
B   C
```

**F**/G

```
result
|   \
A   obj2
   /    \
 obj4    obj5
  |   \     |
 obj3  E    F
  |  \
 obj1  D
 / \
B   C
```

F/**G**

```
result
|   \
A   obj2
   /    \
 obj4    obj5
  |   \     | \
 obj3  E    F  G
  |  \
 obj1  D
 / \
B   C
```

once tree is complete, start computing from bottom to top(all leafs) then all branchs whose leafs are complete.

- B+C = obj1
- B+C+D =obj3
- B+C+D+E =obj4
- F/G = obj5
- (B+C+D+E)+F/G = obj2
- A+(B+C+D+E)+F/G = result